# Using Jquery $When to make async and sync function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I need to make a async call and a synchronous call and when both the calls are over, I need to call another function. I am using JQuery when for this purpose. This functions works fine when I make multiple async calls but when I make synchronous call, I get error. I am using below code to make the call.

```
var requestTwo = function() {
        var v = 10;
        var j = 20;
        var k = v + j;
    };

    $.when($.get(url, function (result, status, xhr) {
        myresult = result;
    })),
    (requestTwo).then(function (r1, r2) {
        //DO something

     });
```

I am getting following error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'then'
```

Comment: requestTwo is not a request, it's a function, so I'm not sure what behaviour you're expecting here.

Comment: `.then()` is something that exists on a promise.  `requestTwo()` does not return a promise so thus you can't call `.then()` on the return value of `requestTwo()`.  Also, `$.when()` is not needed for a single `$.get()`.  `$.when()` is used when you want to wait until multiple promises are done.  And, lastly, if `requestTwo()` is just a normal synchronous function call, you just call it directly.  You don't need any of the extra callback or `.then()` stuff for a regular function call.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$.when` for synchronous function calls, just call them

```
$.get(url, function (result, status, xhr) {
    var myresult = result;
    requestTwo();
     // DO something here, it's synchronous and single threaded, 
     // so the function will be finished
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your second argument of 'when' function must be a promise. Look here http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/#promises. And it seems to be a typo in your code